# Not getting SQLite tables on specific device brand ZTE-Z982 N9560

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

We are getting the SQLite exception of "No such Table found". This issue is only reported on the device with brand ZTE(Z982 & N95630). On all other device the DB is working fine so not able to reproduce. Is ther issue with the Database path?

**Below is the SQLite Helper class that we are using**

```
public ExternalDbOpenHelper( Context context, String databaseName ) {
    super( context, databaseName, null, DB_VERSION );
    this.context = context;
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    DB_PATH = String.format( "//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName );
    DB_NAME = databaseName;

    openDataBase();
}
```

**Method to create Database**

```
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if ( dbExist ) {
        Log.i( this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists" );
        try {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        catch ( SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException sqr ) {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqr.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if ( !dbExist ) {
        try {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        catch ( SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException sqr ) {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqr.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e( this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error" );
        }
    }
}
```

**Datbase exists or not**

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File   file = new File( path );
        if ( file.exists() && !file.isDirectory() ) {
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE );

        }
    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e( this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db" );
    }
    if ( checkDb != null ) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;

}


public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if ( database == null ) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE );

        try {
            database.setVersion(DB_VERSION);
        }catch (SQLiteDiskIOException dio){
            dio.printStackTrace();
            database.setVersion(DB_VERSION);
        }
    }
    return database;
}


public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db ) {
    Log.e( "Node ", "onCreate Database Deleting and Copying latest DB" );
}
```

**DB helper methods**

```
public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) {
    Log.e( "Node ", "onUpgrade Database Deleting and Copying latest DB" );
    if ( oldVersion < newVersion ) {
        Log.v( "Test", "Within onUpgrade. Old is: " + oldVersion + " New is: " + newVersion );
         //getFavorites( db) ;
        context.deleteDatabase( DB_NAME );
        try {
            copyDataBase();
             //setFavorites( db );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // new BackupDBAsync(context).execute();
    }
}
```

**This how we get the SQLiteHelper's instance**

```
dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper( getActivity(), AppConstants.DB_NAME );
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
```

Comment: Hello Sandy_4693 I have exactly the same problem, my database code (mostly equal as yours) seems to be working well in all Android devices except on ZTE. I can not find any solution, did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @Wonton no dude, didn't find any solution to it.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @observer no, and during last days this problem is happening too with Google Pixel. I'll try with Google support.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.close();
```

before

```
copyDataBase();
```